# writing a function to bootstrap CIs

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute the bootstrapped CI for a statistic measure called CoRR but the function is running for up to 200 iterations and stops if I give it more than 200.

```
library(boot)

corr<-function(x,i){

  x2<-x[i,]

rr_c<-epi.2by2((xtabs(~PRSH + depr, data=x2)[c(2,1), c(2,1)]))$res$RR.crude.wald[[1]]

rr_a<- epi.2by2((xtabs(~PRSH + depr + DHHGAGE, data=x2)[c(2,1), c(2,1),]))$res$RR.mh.wald[[1]]

return(abs(log(rr_c/rr_a)))
}

boot.corr<- boot(data=data, statistic=corr,R=1000)

boot.ci(boot.corr, type="perc")
```

and this is how I have my variables coded:

```
data<-subset(d, select=c(GEN_01, DHH_SEX, DEPDDPS, SDCFIMM, MHPFLSA, DHHGAGE))

data$PRSH<-ifelse(data$GEN_01 ==4 | data$GEN_01 ==5, 1, 0)

data$sex <- ifelse(data$DHH_SEX==2,1,0)

data$depr<-ifelse(data$DEPDDPS ==9, NA, ifelse(data$DEPDDPS ==1, 1, 0))
```

This is the error it produces: if (score > z) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: How many NAs do you get with data$depr<-ifelse(data$DEPDDPS ==9, NA, ifelse(data$DEPDDPS ==1, 1, 0)) ? Because when you hit a lot of NA in your bootstrap, does the xtab still works?

Comment: Best thing to do it is write a lapply or for loop to capture the index, i and when the error occurs